# How to select_related on reverse foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A left outer reverse select_related in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975558/a-left-outer-reverse-select-related-in-django)

A `BlogPost` has many `Comment`s. I want to get a list of `BlogPost`s and all their comments.

Thus, I have

```
BlogPost.objects.filter(my_filter).select_related()
```

But the ForeignKey is on the `Comment`, not the `BlogPost`, so the `select_related()` doesn't prefetch any comments. Is there a way to get this to work?

I can't reverse the query (`Comment.objects...`) because then the other objects that the `select_related()` *does* fetch wouldn't work. I need it to work both ways.

Answer (score -1):

Why won't you fetch the comments and then use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) template tag to display them:

```
# Select all Comments with BlogPost data - one query
comments = Comment.objects.select_related('blog_post').order_by('-blog_post').all()
```

Then in template:

```
{% regroup comments by blog_post as posts %}
{% for blog_post in posts %}

    <p>Blog post {{ blog_post.title }}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for comment in blog_post.comments %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think because of my last paragraph. `BlogPost` has other foreign keys that `select_related` *does* work on, and I want it to continue working on those. By fetching the comments first you're just shifting the problem.

Comment: Another problem with this solution is that it won't get blog posts with no Comments