# Django Outer Join

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm creating a small web application to track my orders, i have two models:

Order(models.Model) " This model to record the new orders"

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGOTRIES)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

OrderHistory(models.Model) " This model to record the changes for each order in any field"

```
class OrderHistory(models.Model):
    version_num = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

View:

```
def update_orders(request,pk):
     theOrder = Order.objects.get(id=pk)


    theHistory = createOrderHistory({
    'Order': theOrder.id,
    'customer': theOrder.customer, 
    'product': theOrder.product, 
    'date_created': theOrder.date_created,
    'status': theOrder.status, 
    'note': theOrder.note
    }) 

    print('The History of the order ',theHistory)
    UpdateForm = createOrder(instance=theOrder)
    theid = pk
    if request.method == 'POST':
        UpdateForm = createOrder(request.POST,instance=theOrder)
    if theHistory.is_valid():
        if UpdateForm.is_valid():
            theHistory.save()
            UpdateForm.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        UpdateForm = createOrder(instance=theOrder) 

    context = {'UpdateForm':UpdateForm} 
    return render(request,'accounts/updateOrder.html',context)
```

In the View `update_orders` function am taking the current order and save it into `OrderHistory` and 
then i save the new changes into `Order` Model

it's working fine but the OrderHistory Model is not including the new change.

`orderHistory` to get the history of the order

```
def orderHistory(request,pk):
    theHistoryOfTheOrder = Order.objects.filter(id=pk).prefetch_related('Order')
    #theHistoryOfTheOrder = Order.objects.filter(id=pk)
    print('the query result is :',theHistoryOfTheOrder)
    context = {'theHistoryOfTheOrder':theHistoryOfTheOrder}
    return render(request,'accounts/orderHistory.html',context)
```

i tried to use `prefetch_related()` since i'm fetching multiple records but it's through an error

```
Cannot find 'Order' on Order object, 'Order' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()
```

i need to get all the records in Order and OrderHistory with the same orderID
also is this the right solution to preform History or is there another good way to do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to save your changes or how to retrieve saved changes? And your intent was probably to filter `OrderHistory`, not `Orders`.

Comment: i need to retrieve the data from both models since it's related Basically an outer join

Comment: Please clarify which model is supposed to be on the left side of the join and on the right side. It's unclear from your code.

Comment: Order should be on the left side so if there is nothing on the OrderHistory and one order on Order it will be retrieve, thank you Ivan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A left outer reverse select\_related in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975558/a-left-outer-reverse-select-related-in-django)